# Where to start learning NodeJS Image Manipulation?

Tags: node.js

I want to learn image manipulation in NodeJS, I know how to do it with .net so I assume NodeJS has the same features I just am having issues finding good documentation on native node ways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a popular library called ImageMagick that you can use for this...

https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

The README.md file should be enough for you to get started. If you are still having trouble with getting started, you can search google or ask a question here (about a specific thing).

Good luck!